# Only one record written to sql server + combobox not refreshed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, oop

I'm new to .net programming and I have a problem writing intput from a form to sql server. Only one record gets written to the database, for the other records it's says "Data not written to database.". Also my cmbbox is not updated after the data is written to the database, though I run method UpdateInitialWeek().
I don't want to write 'spaghetti code' and would love my program to be a structured one. So any advice is greatly appreciated (I already know it's better to use the Entity Framework to deal with data, something I will learn eventually ;)).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Write_to_database
{
    public partial class WriteToDatabase : Form
    {
        SqlServer sql = new SqlServer();

        public WriteToDatabase()
        {
            sql.OpenSqlConnection();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.UpdateInitialWeek();
            sql.CloseSqlConnection();
        }

        private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToOutput(sql.OpenSqlConnection());
            if (txtMilitaryPress.Text != "")
                WriteToOutput(sql.InsertToTraining(ConvertDate(dtMilitaryPress.Value), "Military Press", txtMilitaryPress.Text.ToString(), txtRepMilitaryPress.Text.ToString(), cmbMilitaryPress.Text.ToString()));
            if (txtDeadlift.Text != "")
                WriteToOutput(sql.InsertToTraining(dtDeadlift.Value.ToString(), "Deadlift", txtDeadlift.Text.ToString(), txtRepDeadlift.Text.ToString(), cmbDeadlift.Text.ToString()));
            if (txtBenchPress.Text != "")
                WriteToOutput(sql.InsertToTraining(dtBenchPress.Value.ToString(), "Bench Press", txtBenchPress.Text.ToString(), txtRepBenchPress.Text.ToString(), cmbBenchPress.Text.ToString()));
            if (txtBackSquat.Text != "")
                WriteToOutput(sql.InsertToTraining(dtBackSquat.Value.ToString(), "Back Squat", txtBackSquat.Text.ToString(), txtRepBackSquat.Text.ToString(), cmbBackSquat.Text.ToString()));
            this.UpdateInitialWeek();
            WriteToOutput(sql.CloseSqlConnection());
        }

        //Write output to textbox
        public void WriteToOutput(string output)
        {
            this.txtOutput.AppendText(output + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        //Convert date for sql server
        public string ConvertDate(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }

        //Update comboboxes to set right training week
        public void UpdateInitialWeek()
        {
            this.cmbBackSquat.Text = CheckWeek(sql.GetDataTraining("Back Squat"));
            this.cmbBenchPress.Text = CheckWeek(sql.GetDataTraining("Bench Press"));
            this.cmbDeadlift.Text = CheckWeek(sql.GetDataTraining("Deadlift"));
            this.cmbMilitaryPress.Text = CheckWeek(sql.GetDataTraining("Military Press"));
        }

        //Training week +1 except for week 4 --> back to 1
        public string CheckWeek(string trainingWeek)
        {
            int trWeek = Int32.Parse(trainingWeek);
            if (trWeek == 4)
                trWeek = 1;
            else
                trWeek += 1;
            return trWeek.ToString();
        }


    }

    public class SqlServer
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        public string OpenSqlConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " successful.";
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " failed.";
            }
        }

        public string CloseSqlConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Close();
                return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " successfully closed";
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " not closed.";
            }
        }

        public string InsertToTraining(string date, string lift, string weight, string reps, string week)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LIFT_HISTORY VALUES(@date,@lift,@weight,@reps,@week)", con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("weight", weight.ToString())); //SqlDbType.NVarChar
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("week", week.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("reps", reps.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("lift", lift.ToString()));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                return "Data successfully written to database.";

            }
            catch
            {
                return "Data not written to database.";
            }
        }

        public string GetDataTraining(string where)
        {
            int trainingWeek;
            //using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT WEEK_OF_TRAINING FROM dbo.LIFT_HISTORY WHERE [DATE] = (SELECT MAX([DATE]) FROM dbo.LIFT_HISTORY WHERE LIFT = 'Deadlift') AND LIFT = 'Deadlift')", con))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT WEEK_OF_TRAINING  FROM dbo.LIFT_HISTORY  WHERE LIFT = '"+ where +"'  ORDER BY [DATE] DESC", con))
            {
                trainingWeek = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            return trainingWeek.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, but it's ok for now that you still learning, for example:

```
    public WriteToDatabase()
    {
        sql.OpenSqlConnection();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.UpdateInitialWeek();
        sql.CloseSqlConnection();
    }
```

should be:

```
    public void WriteToDatabase()
    {
        sql.OpenSqlConnection();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.UpdateInitialWeek();
        sql.CloseSqlConnection();
    }
```

That's because you're not returning anything, instead of that you shoud to declare the type of variable that you're returning on.

Well first of all I'd like to suggest you to use a layer-oriented coding. For example:

I'll start crating an entity class:

```
namespace Entities
{
public class LiftingStory
  {
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Week { get; set; }
    public string Reps { get; set; }
    public string Lift { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Then you start creating "Data-Access" Layer

```
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using Entities;

namespace DataAccess
{
public class DataLiftingStory
{
    public bool insertLifting(LiftingStory obj) //correction: should be LiftingStory instead of DataLiftingStory because I'm retrieving a LiftingStory objecto to be proccesed.
    {
        //we're creating a new connection to Database, but it will need string parameter
        //you can get it directly from the connectionstring on the Web.config in this way
        // ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameParameterOfYourConnString"].ConnectionString
        //instead of that I'll do it with a string for making more easier to understand

        string connectionString = "Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            //now I'll create the command
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {

                //so now I've to say what type of command I'm making up. In your case is "Text" because you're being explicit with the query
                //I suggest you to use stored procedures btw.
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                //now the command text will be your query
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LIFT_HISTORY VALUES(@date,@lift,@weight,@reps,@week)";

                //now we set the parameters
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date", obj.Date));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("lift", obj.Lift));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("weight", obj.Weight));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("reps", obj.Reps));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("week", obj.Week));

                try
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.Connection.Open();

                    //now we're executing the query and if we get more than 0 that will means that it inserted or modified a row
                    //then it will return true and going out from method.
                    if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //If it fails return false
                    return false;
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    //then we close the connection
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }

            //if not failed but it didn't anything, it will return false
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it's the easy part Business.

```
 using System.Web;
 using Entities;
 using DataAccess;
 namespace Business
 {
   public class BusinessLiftingStory
  {
    public bool insertLifting(LiftingStory obj)
    {
        DataLiftingStory dataLifting = new DataLiftingStory();
        dataLifting.insertLifting(obj);
    }
   }
 }
```

So the last step is to fill the object in the "View-layer" and call the method from Business:

```
        LiftingStory obj = new LiftingStory();
        obj.Weight = string.Empty;
        obj.Date = string.Empty; //put values from comboBoxes
        obj.Reps = string.Empty;
        obj.Lift = string.Empty;
        obj.Week = string.Empty;
        BusinessLiftingStory busObj = new BusinessLiftingStory();
        busObj.insertLifting(obj);
```

Combo boxes are not refreshing data because the DataBind() method, dont forget in the moment when you want to "redraw" your comboBox you'll have to set `DataSource = null` then get the datasource again and then dataBind.

use a method Init() for that if you want.

```
 private void Init()
 {
     cmbWeight.DataSource = null;
     cmbWeight.DataSource = //new Datasource
     //dont forget to set the values and text fields
     cmbWeight.DataBind();
 }
```

In that way you'll have a order in your code, , I hope it would help you.

Greetings :)

PS: sorry for the extended answer.

Comment: Great answer. Wrap your connection and command object in Using statements for a +1 :)

Comment: Thanks Pablo, really good that you gave such an extended answer :)!!  This is very usefull information for me!

Comment: Thank you for advice @HardCode I was doing it for educational purposes ahahaha, but it's better teaching "best practices" immediately :)

Comment: Alright, so i'm trying to implement the code and gain understanding. Are the different layers in different cs files? Like Entities.cs, DataAccess.cs and so on? Once again I would like to thank you for your answer, this is great to learn best practice from the start :)

Comment: Layers must be on different "Class Library" just for grouping classes from the same "Layer". And if you require another class from other Class Library don't forget to "Add Reference" to the Class library you're trying to work with and its respective "using" calling the Class Library.

I know it's so much information at once, but you'll get it.

Comment: Check this image on the [link](http://i.imgur.com/TE3m5SR.png) Sorry it's in spanish but you'll understand, those are Class Libraries and the WebApp it's the "View-Layer"

Comment: Thanks, the image is clear indeed :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

maybe try printing out the exception details either to your return string or console, etc.

instead of 
        catch
                   {
                       return "Data not written to database.";
                   }

..

```
   catch( Exception ex )
               {
                   return "Data not written to database." + ex.Message;
               }
```

..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message(v=vs.110).aspx